# Seeamlessly share clipboard between computers through the internet?

Tags: networking, clipboard

I have the following setup with this problem which forbids me from using normal ways to share clipboard between computers.

- Machine A: This is my personal desktop where I have a Logitech receiver connected to a MK850 mouse & keyboard kit.
- Machine B: This is my work laptop where I connected my MK850 through Bluetooth, I can switch to it using the mouse and keyboard buttons to switch.

Now, the problem is that I need to connect to a VPN in machine B which completely kills my local network connection, this causes that other solutions I could find (Mouse Without Borders, Logitech Flow) won't work because they use the local network to connect and share the data. I do not have access to any sort of settings or preferences in the VPN client as it's all managed by the security team, so I cannot set it to avoid it killing my local network.

I'm thinking that if instead of using the local network, there was a way to use a remote connection on the internet as a middle man it could work (only for the clipboard of course, the lag would make it impossible to use the mouse comfortably). I'm currently using a Google Keep note as a workaround but it requires me to ctrl-c in one machine, ctrl-v in that machine in the Keep note, switch to the other machine, ctrl-c from the note and finally ctrl-v where I want it.

Is there any **safe** software or service (preferably free) which can accomplish this but automatically sending the data when I ctrl-c and automatically pulling the data from the remote server into the second machine clipboard? I have seen several "over the internet clipboards" like cl1p.net or ipshare.net but are just a webpage where I also have to paste what I want to transfer.

Comment: No, the VPN requires device authorization through a vendor specific software provided by my employer.

Comment: You can try synergy for this, not sure if it's still freeware... The version I'm using is. If you port-forward to the master running the server application, you should be able to have machine-b connect through the internet. The best option here is to contact the security team, see if it would violate their policy to set up a route in the host O.S of machine-b to allow it to communicate on your local subnet outside of the encrypted tunnel. (**This is assuming that machine-b is company property**)

Comment: https://symless.com/synergy no longer freeware, but I'm sure if you look you can still find the older (free) versions out there

Comment: Any luck with trying that out?

Comment: Couldn't find a trustworthy free version of Synergy. I'm going to stick to the Google Keep note for now.

Comment: I have an older version installer if you want it. Scanned with norton 360. It's clean, and still under the freeware license.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found so crafted by my own. Little node utility, open source. Using this for sharing clipboard between my mac and ubuntu. VPN and other network issues - on your own.

https://github.com/leplik/netpaste

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Explaining HOW to use this tool will make it an answer. Right now it is only a comment. Use the EDIT button to correct this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1243258)